# Trying to understand code that computes the gradient wrt to the input for LogSoftMax in Torch

Tags: mathematical-optimization, torch, gradient-descent, softmax

Code comes from: https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/lib/THNN/generic/LogSoftMax.c

I don't see how this code is computing the gradient w.r.t to the input for the module LogSoftMax. What I'm confused about is what the two for loops are doing.

```
for (t = 0; t < nframe; t++)
{
sum = 0;
gradInput_data = gradInput_data0 + dim*t;
output_data = output_data0 + dim*t;
gradOutput_data = gradOutput_data0 + dim*t;

for (d = 0; d < dim; d++)
  sum += gradOutput_data[d];

for (d = 0; d < dim; d++)
  gradInput_data[d] = gradOutput_data[d] - exp(output_data[d])*sum;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At forward time we have (with x = input vector, y = output vector, f = logsoftmax, i = i-th component):

```
yi = f(xi)
   = log( exp(xi) / sum_j(exp(xj)) )
   = xi - log( sum_j(exp(xj)) )
```

When computing the jacobian Jf of f you have (i-th row):

```
dyi/dxi = 1 - exp(xi) / sum_j(exp(xj))
```

And for k different than i:

```
dyi/dxk = - exp(xk) / sum_j(exp(xj))
```

This gives for Jf:

```
1-E(x1)     -E(x2)     -E(x3)    ...
 -E(x1)    1-E(x2)     -E(x3)    ...
 -E(x1)     -E(x2)    1-E(x3)    ...
...
```

With `E(xi) = exp(xi) / sum_j(exp(xj))`

If we name gradInput the gradient w.r.t input and gradOutput the gradient w.r.t output the backpropagation gives (chain rule):

```
gradInputi = sum_j( gradOutputj . dyj/dxi )
```

This is equivalent to:

```
gradInput = transpose(Jf) . gradOutput
```

Which finally gives for the i-th component:

```
gradInputi = gradOutputi - E(xi) . sum_j( gradOutputj )
```

So the first loop pre-computes `sum_j( gradOutputj )` and the last one the above term, i.e. i-th component of grad. input - except there is a missing `1 / sum_j(exp(xj))` for the exponential term in the Torch implementation (*the above calculus should probably be double checked even though it sounds correct and explains the current implementation*).

**UPDATE**: there is no problem with the *missing* `1 / sum_j(exp(xj))` term. Since the the jacobian is computed on the *output* value, and since this formerly computed output is precisely a log-softmax distribution it comes that the sum-exp of this distribution is 1:

```
sum_j(exp(outputj)) = sum_j(exp( log(exp(inputj) / sum_k(exp(inputk) ))
                    = sum_j(         exp(inputj) / sum_k(exp(inputk)  )
                    = 1
```

So there is no need to explicit this term in the implementation, which gives (for x = output):

```
gradInputi = gradOutputi - exp(outputi) . sum_j( gradOutputj )
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense until you get to the comments about the missing summation term + the update explaining it.  There is nothing missing. E(xi) = e^gradoutput. Elementary algebraic manipulation of the yi equation in terms of E(xi) will yield the answer. The Jacobian is always computed at the input coordinate, not the output!