# How to write the updateGradInput and accGradParameters in torch?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, torch, gradient-descent

I know the two functions are for torch's backward propagation and the interface is as follows

`updateGradInput(input, gradOutput)
accGradParameters(input, gradOutput, scale)`

I'm confused about what the `gradInput` and `gradOutput` really mean in a layer.
Assume the network's cost is `C` and a layer `L`. Do `gradInput` and `gradOutput` of layer `L` mean `d_C/d_input_L` and `d_C/d_output_L`?

If so, how to compute `gradInput` accorading to `gradOutput`?

Moreover, does `accGradParameters` mean to accumulate `d_C/d_Weight_L` and `d_C/d_bias_L`? If so, how to compute these values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do `gradInput` and `gradOutput` of layer L mean `d_C/d_input_L` and `d_C/d_output_L`

Yes:

- `gradInput` = derivative of the cost w.r.t layer's input,
- `gradOutput` = derivative of the cost w.r.t layer's output.

> how to compute `gradInput` according to `gradOutput`

Adapting the schema from [The building blocks of Deep Learning](http://deepdish.io/2015/11/21/building-blocks-of-deep-learning/) (**warning**: in this schema the cost is denoted `L` = `Loss`, and the layer `f`) we have:

[image]

For a concrete, step-by-step example of such a computation on a LogSoftMax layer you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328031/1688185).

> does `accGradParameters` mean to accumulate `d_C/d_Weight_L` and `d_C/d_bias_L`

Yes. Named `gradWeight` and `gradBias` in torch/nn.

> how to compute these values?

Similarly as above. Still using a formula from the above blog post:

[image]

Except the jacobian has not the same dimensionality (see the blog post for more details). As an example, for a Linear layer this translates into:

[image]

This is the outer product between the layer's input and `gradOutput`. In Torch [we have](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/872f4b9407368e1190d38d01775f13994c517f28/Linear.lua#L90):

```
self.gradWeight:addr(scale, gradOutput, input)
```

And:

[image]

Which is `gradOutput`. In Torch [we have](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/872f4b9407368e1190d38d01775f13994c517f28/Linear.lua#L91):

```
self.gradBias:add(scale, gradOutput)
```

In both cases `scale` is a scale factor used in practice as the learning rate.